# Make tabs in PyQt6 start from the right instead of the left

Tags: python, pyqt6

Hi i have this simple text edit program in pyqt6 and i want to know how do i make the tabs appear on the right instead of the default the left. Please can't find it anywhere and i'm getting tired.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QTabWidget

class TextEditor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.textedit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textedit)

        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.tab_widget.setMovable(True)
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.textedit, "Untitled")

        self.tab_widget.tabBar().setExpanding(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Text Editor')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    editor = TextEditor()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: `self.tab_widget.setStyleSheet('QTabWidget::tab-bar{ alignment: right; }')`. See the stylesheet documentation about [QTabWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qtabwidget-widget) and [QTabBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qtabbar-widget). Also, always use `setCentralWidget()` with the *actual* central widget and avoid calling it for the wrong widget: remove `self.setCentralWidget(self.textedit)`, since you're adding the text edit to the tab widget.